# Spring context:property-placeholder file not found

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar, maven-assembly-plugin

I am trying to build a stand alone Spring based Java application.

I am using Maven assembly plugin to build the JAR with dependencies. The strcture of the JAR ends up looking like this (Just a subset):

```
com
META-INF
org
properties
 - taskexecutor.properties
spring
 - properties.xml
.
.
.
```

Manifest looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: authorname
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_30
Main-Class: com.company.utilities.task.TaskLauncher
```

When the application runs the property placeholder should be configured by including the properties.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/properties/taskExecutor.properties"/>

</beans>
```

It runs fine in Eclipse, but when I run the JAR I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileN
otFoundException: class path resource [properties/taskExecutor.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:78)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:663)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:638)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:407)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at com.company.utilities.task.TaskLauncher.main(TaskLauncher.java:28)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [properties/taskExecutor.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:181)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:161)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:69)
        ... 6 more
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears running through the command line is case sensitive but Eclipse is not when loading these resources.

Renaming `taskexecutor.properties` to `taskExecutor.properties` fixed the issue. Oops. Hopefully this helps someone equally as stupid as me in the future ;-)

Answer (score 0):

move taskExecutor.properties to root and try it

```
<context:property-placeholder location="taskExecutor.properties"/>
```